# element.on("click", ...) don't trigger $watch

Tags: angularjs, onclick, watch

Why does not the click event fire $watch in the code below? If I include `$apply`, $watch is triggered.

```
angulartest.factory("Fac", function () {
  var v = "foo";
  return {
    getV: function () {
      return v;
    },  
    setV: function (v_) {
      v = v_; 
    }   
  };  
});

angulartest.directive("wdirective", function (Fac) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<p>Hello</p>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on("click", function (event) {
        Fac.setV("bar");
        //scope.$apply();  <-- Need this to fire $watch
      }); 
    }   
  };  
});

angulartest.controller("wController", function($scope, Fac) {

  $scope.$watch(Fac.getV, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("v = " + newValue);
  }); 

});
```

Comment: Extending @tymeJV's answer- you might checkout [when to use $scope.$apply](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29) on the Angular github page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Angulars `$digest` cycle is not triggered by pure JS click events.

Comment: Is there another more AngularJS way to set a click event, which will trigger the `$digest` cycle?

Comment: OK, I noticed `ng-click`.